# Can't get URL from routes without a request in my Play application

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

I would like to get a url from my service class like this:

```
val bookingInquiryUrl = routes.BookingController.showBookingInquiry(booking.bookingId.toString).absoluteURL()
```

But this results in a error `Cannot find any HTTP Request Header here`, and I know this is because it don't have assess to a Request. But, in my case this is exactly what I want to do. In my application I have a scheduled job that calls my service class which will send an email with the url to the `showBookingInquiry` page. Therefor I don't have any Request.

So my question is, is there any other way to generate url (without the Request)?

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
val bookingInquiryUrl = routes.BookingController.showBookingInquiry(booking.bookingId.toString).url
```